# Cannot insert data into database, no error message displayed

Tags: asp.net

I cannot insert data into a database and I get no error message. I link both table `patientRegister` and `patientAdmission` by declaring `patientNRIC` as foreign key. Below are the codes.

**patientNOK.cs**

```
 public class patientNOK
{
    public string nokWardClass { get; set; }
    public DateTime nokAdDT { get; set; }
    public string nokFName { get; set; }
    public string nokLName { get; set; }
    public string nokNRIC { get; set; }
    public DateTime nokDOB { get; set; }
    public string nokGender { get; set; }
    public string nokNationality { get; set; }
    public string nokRelationship { get; set; }
    public int nokContactH { get; set; }
    public int nokContactHP { get; set; }
    public string nokEmail { get; set; }
    public string nokAddr1 { get; set; }
    public string nokAddr2 { get; set; }
    public string nokState { get; set; }
    public string nokZIP { get; set; }
    public string nokCountry { get; set; }
    public DateTime dischargeDT { get; set; }
    public string patientNRICForiegn { get; set; }
}

 public class patientNOKDAO
{
    string DBConnect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString;

    public int InsertNOK(string wardClass , DateTime admissionDT, string nokFName, string nokLName, string nokNRIC, DateTime nokDOB, string nokGender, string nokNationality, string nokRelationship, int nokContactH, int nokContactHP, string nokEmail, string nokAddr1, string nokAddr2, string nokState, int nokZIP, string nokCountry, DateTime dischargeDT, string patientNRIC)
    {
        StringBuilder sqlStr = new StringBuilder();
        int result = 0;
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

        sqlStr.AppendLine("Insert INTO patientAdmission( wardClass, admissionDT, patientNokFname, patientNokLname, patientNokNRIC, patientNOKDOB");

        sqlStr.AppendLine("patientNokGender, patientNokNationality, patientNokRelationship, patientNokContactH, patientNokContactHP, patientNokEmail");

        sqlStr.AppendLine("patientNokAddr1, patientNokAddr2, patientNokZIP, patientNokCountry, dischargeDateTime,patientNRIC)");

        sqlStr.AppendLine("VALUES (@parawardClass,@paraadmissonDT,@parapatientNokFname,@parapatientNokLname,@parapatientNokNRIC, @parapatientNOKDOB,@parapatientNokGender,@parapatientNokNationality");
        sqlStr.AppendLine("@parapatientNokRelationship,@parapatientNokContactH,@parapatientNokContactHP,@parapatientNokEmail,@parapatientNokAddr1,@parapatientNokAddr2,@parapatientNokState,@parapatientNokZIP");
        sqlStr.AppendLine("@parapatientNokCountry,@paradischargeDateTime,@parapatientNRIC)");

        try
        {
            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(DBConnect);
            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr.ToString(), myConn);

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parawardClass", wardClass);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paraadmissionDT", admissionDT);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokFname", nokFName);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokLname", nokLName);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokNRIC", nokNRIC);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNOKDOB", nokDOB);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokGender", nokGender);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokNationality", nokNationality);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokRelationship", nokRelationship);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokContactH", nokContactH);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokContactHP", nokContactHP);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokEmail", nokEmail);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokAddr1", nokAddr1);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokAddr2", nokAddr2);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokState", nokState);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokZIP", nokZIP);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNokCountry", nokCountry);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paradischargeDateTime", dischargeDT);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parapatientNRIC", patientNRIC);

            myConn.Open();
            result = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            myConn.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            logManager log = new logManager();
            log.addLog("patientNOKDAO.InsertNOK", sqlStr.ToString(), ex);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**UI**

```
 string wardPreference = ddl1.SelectedValue;

        string admissionDischargeDT = adDT.Text;
        string admissionDT = admissionDischargeDT.Substring(0,19);
        string dischargeDT = admissionDischargeDT.Substring(22,19);

        DateTime admissionDTinput = DateTime.ParseExact(admissionDT,"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        DateTime dischargeDTinput = DateTime.ParseExact(dischargeDT, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        string FNameNOK = TextBoxNOKFname.Text;
        string LNameNOK = TextBoxNOKLname.Text;
        string nricNOK = TextBoxNOKNRIC.Text;
       //
        DateTime dobNOK = DateTime.ParseExact(nokDOB.Text.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string selectedNOKGender = null;
        if(Request.Form["radio-unstyled-inline-left"] !=null)
        {
            selectedNOKGender = Request.Form["radio-unstyled-inline-left"].ToString();
        }

        string nationalityNok = TextBoxNOKNationality.Text;
        string relationshipNOK = DropDownListRelationship.SelectedValue;

        int nokContactH = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxNOKContactH.Text);
        int nokContactHP = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxNOKContactHP.Text);
        string nokEmail = TextBoxNOKContactEmail.Text;
        string nokAddr1 = TextBoxNOKAddr1.Text;
        string nokAddr2 = TextBoxNOKAddr2.Text;
        string nokState = TextBoxNOKState.Text;
        int nokZIP = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxNOKZIP.Text);
        string nokCountry = TextBoxNOKCountry.Text;
        string patientNRIC = TextBoxNRIC.Text;

        try
        {
            patientNOKDAO fmNOK = new patientNOKDAO();

            int insNOK = fmNOK.InsertNOK(wardPreference, admissionDTinput, FNameNOK, LNameNOK, nricNOK, dobNOK, selectedNOKGender, nationalityNok, relationshipNOK, nokContactH, nokContactHP, nokEmail, nokAddr1, nokAddr2, nokState, nokZIP, nokCountry, dischargeDTinput, patientNRIC);

            if (insNOK == 1)
            {
                TextBoxAddr1.Text = "Sucess";
            }
            else
            {
                TextBoxAddr1.Text = "FAILURE";
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            TextBoxAddr1.Text = "error";
        }
    }
```

I tried viewing the log file it shows this , apparently there is a problem at the NOK class

> Exception Type: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Exception:
>   Incorrect syntax near 'patientNokGender'. Source:
>   patientNOKDAO.InsertNOK sql command:Insert INTO patientAdmission(
>   wardClass, admissionDT, patientNokFname, patientNokLname,
>   patientNokNRIC, patientNOKDOB patientNokGender, patientNokNationality,
>   patientNokRelationship, patientNokContactH, patientNokContactHP,
>   patientNokEmail patientNokAddr1, patientNokAddr2, patientNokZIP,
>   patientNokCountry, dischargeDateTime,patientNRIC) VALUES
>   (@parawardClass,@paraadmissonDT,@parapatientNokFname,@parapatientNokLname,@parapatientNokNRIC,
>   @parapatientNOKDOB,@parapatientNokGender,@parapatientNokNationality
>   @parapatientNokRelationship,@parapatientNokContactH,@parapatientNokContactHP,@parapatientNokEmail,@parapatientNokAddr1,@parapatientNokAddr2,@parapatientNokState,@parapatientNokZIP
>   @parapatientNokCountry,@paradischargeDateTime,@parapatientNRIC)

Comment: Try debugging and check the logs.

Comment: What is the value of `result` when you execute your code?

Answer (score 0):

can u please test final generated sql command .
in this kind of problems i run sqlCmd in a new query in microsoft sql server .

Comment: Hi, how do i actually do it?

Comment: dear @GX-X  please insert a break point on that line result = your sqlCmnd and run your application . then copy value of sqlCmd and paste in new sql query windows in microsoft sql server and run it .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing commas at certain points in your string concatenation, the first being here:

> patientNOKDOB patientNokGender

The other is here:

> patientNokEmail patientNokAddr1

Here is the cause:

```
sqlStr.AppendLine("Insert INTO patientAdmission( wardClass, admissionDT, patientNokFname, patientNokLname, patientNokNRIC, patientNOKDOB");

sqlStr.AppendLine("patientNokGender, patientNokNationality, patientNokRelationship, patientNokContactH, patientNokContactHP, patientNokEmail");
```

You'll also want to make sure you're adding the commas to the values string concatenation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Update your below lines-

```
sqlStr.AppendLine("Insert INTO patientAdmission( wardClass, admissionDT, patientNokFname, patientNokLname, patientNokNRIC, patientNOKDOB");
sqlStr.AppendLine("patientNokGender, patientNokNationality, patientNokRelationship, patientNokContactH, patientNokContactHP, patientNokEmail");
sqlStr.AppendLine("patientNokAddr1, patientNokAddr2, patientNokZIP, patientNokCountry, dischargeDateTime,patientNRIC)");
sqlStr.AppendLine("VALUES (@parawardClass,@paraadmissonDT,@parapatientNokFname,@parapatientNokLname,@parapatientNokNRIC, @parapatientNOKDOB,@parapatientNokGender,@parapatientNokNationality");
sqlStr.AppendLine("@parapatientNokRelationship,@parapatientNokContactH,@parapatientNokContactHP,@parapatientNokEmail,@parapatientNokAddr1,@parapatientNokAddr2,@parapatientNokState,@parapatientNokZIP");
sqlStr.AppendLine("@parapatientNokCountry,@paradischargeDateTime,@parapatientNRIC)");
```

with

```
sqlStr.AppendLine("Insert INTO patientAdmission( wardClass, admissionDT, patientNokFname, patientNokLname, patientNokNRIC, patientNOKDOB, ");
sqlStr.AppendLine("patientNokGender, patientNokNationality, patientNokRelationship, patientNokContactH, patientNokContactHP, patientNokEmail, ");
sqlStr.AppendLine("patientNokAddr1, patientNokAddr2, patientNokZIP, patientNokCountry, dischargeDateTime,patientNRIC)");
sqlStr.AppendLine("VALUES (@parawardClass,@paraadmissonDT,@parapatientNokFname,@parapatientNokLname,@parapatientNokNRIC, @parapatientNOKDOB,@parapatientNokGender,@parapatientNokNationality, ");
sqlStr.AppendLine("@parapatientNokRelationship,@parapatientNokContactH,@parapatientNokContactHP,@parapatientNokEmail,@parapatientNokAddr1,@parapatientNokAddr2,@parapatientNokState,@parapatientNokZIP, ");
sqlStr.AppendLine("@parapatientNokCountry,@paradischargeDateTime,@parapatientNRIC)");
```

Just appended ", " to your first, second, fourth and fifth lines for proper SQL formation.